# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I'm receiving this error when the code look for the path, I dont understand whe this happend, I think im doing right.

Code:

```
 string newUri = ImageGalleryUri.Replace("ms-appdatalocal/", "");  //Replace this part of the string with a nonspace character.
        newUri = newUri.Replace("/", "\\");
        newUri = newUri.Replace("%20", " "); //Replace the ASCII code for space for an actual space. For some reason I'm getting invalid character error with %20.
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(newUri);
        DataPackage dp = new DataPackage();    //Create the DataPackage containing the clipboard content.
        dp.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(storageFile));
        Clipboard.SetContent(dp);
        await successDialog.ShowAsync();
```

The error is in this line: newUri = ms-appdata:\local\Books\Assets\Recursos para el docente\Matematicas\9\Esp\1\0\Geometria_Page_04.png

```
StorageFile storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(newUri);
```

Comment: What is the value of `newUri`?

Comment: Which line is this happening on? Have you debugged to check the actual value of the string you're constructing and then subsequently getting an error on? We have no way of knowing what the string is when you get this error.

Comment: I edit the question with the error line.

Comment: The value of the variable is: ms-appdata:\\local\\Books\\Assets\\Recursos para el docente\\Matematicas\\9\\Esp\\1\\0\\Geometria_Page_04.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
newUri = Uri.EscapeDataString(newUri);
```

Instead of:

```
newUri = newUri.Replace("%20", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Debug to check the actual value of the string.
2. Windows + R, then copy the string and see if it opens.
3. See if all slashes/backslashes are properly escaped (I don't think it's correct to use backslashes here).
4. Create a file named file.txt and try this:

   using Windows.Storage;

StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync("ms-appdata:///local/file.txt");

1. Try replacing the argument passed in the function above with your string.